# After assigning a value to field of record through VBA, form data becomes editable

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form that I'm using as subform. I set Property Sheet--> Data --> `Allow edits` to `NO`

I need to assign a value to first field in my record, and for that I use VBA on form's current event:

> first_field = Me.CurrentRecord

But then my form data becomes editable. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you just set `Me.AllowEdits = False` after running the above code?

Comment: I already tried it, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As to why the AllowEdits property changes, I cannot answer that. Have you checked the value of the AllowEdits property once these edits are allowed?

It isn't clear to me why you need to set `first_field = Me.CurrentRecord` on your form's current event. If you're using it to display the index of the current record to your user, consider using a label instead of a field: `Me.lblHeader.Caption = Me.CurrentRecord`

When it comes to disallowing edits in forms, there are a couple other approaches you might consider.

1) If you're using a subform, you can disable the entire subform control which will prevent edits. If you're not using a subform, you could always consider using one. Usually you can get the same exact look and feel using another form as your Main form, if there's some advantage to be gained through it.

2) You can use a loop that loops through all of the controls and locks or unlocks them. You'll have to build the logic somewhere that determines when to lock or unlock them, but a single function should be capable of loop through all the editable controls and setting their Locked property to either true or false.